# Help me optimize my Line Of Sight on a 2d grid algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, line-of-sight

```
    private bool LOSBetween2Nodes( int2 start , int2 end )
    {
        int2 dif = new int2(
            math.abs( end.x - start.x ) ,
            math.abs( end.y - start.y ) );
        int2 pos = new int2(
            start.x ,
            start.y );
        int2 inc = new int2(
            ( end.x > start.x ) ? 1 : -1 ,
            ( end.y > start.y ) ? 1 : -1 );

        int numIterations = 1 + dif.x + dif.y;
        int error = dif.x - dif.y;
        int walkable = 0;
        bool prevY = false;
        int numSameDir = 0;

        if ( error <= 0 )
            prevY = true;

        dif.x *= 2;
        dif.y *= 2;

        for ( ; numIterations > 0; --numIterations )
        {
            walkable += graphNodeWalkables[ pos.x + pos.y * graphCellLength ];

            if ( numSameDir < 1 )
            {
                if ( prevY )
                    walkable += graphNodeWalkables[ ( pos.x - inc.x ) + pos.y * graphCellLength ];
                else
                    walkable += graphNodeWalkables[ pos.x + ( pos.y - inc.y ) * graphCellLength ];

                if ( error > 0 ) // more steps in x
                {
                    pos.x += inc.x;

                    if ( !prevY )
                        numSameDir++;
                    else
                        numSameDir = 0;

                    prevY = false;
                    error -= dif.y;
                }
                else // more steps in y
                {
                    pos.y += inc.y;

                    if ( prevY )
                        numSameDir++;
                    else
                        numSameDir = 0;

                    prevY = true;
                    error += dif.x;
                }
            }
        }

        return walkable == 0;
    }
```

This currently checks all grid cells along a line between a certain width and returns telling you if any are unwalkable. This can run thousands-tens of thousands of times a frame.

Comment: Has your profiling of this method identified any specific bottleneck?

Comment: The extra if-checks on prevY is a minor performance hit. Is there a way I can re-structure this algorithm to omit those checks for some sort of equation instead?